# How to get variable from middleware?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I've created my own middleware for API. Following is my code for getting valid User details based on the request params `access_token`

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Exceptions\GeneralException;
use App\Models\Access\User\User;

class authNS
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        try {

            $user = User::where("access_token",$request->header('access-token'))->with('details')->first();

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            return response()->json(['error'=>'Something is wrong']);

        }

        return $next($request);

    }
}
```

But how can I access this `$user` variable within my `Controller`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`onceUsingId()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.html#method_onceUsingId) to log a user into the application for a single request. No sessions or cookies will be utilized, which means this method may be helpful when building a stateless API:

So in your `middleware` you can use it as:

```
$user = User::where("access_token",$request->header('access-token'))->first();

if($user) {
   auth()->onceUsingId($user->id);
}
```

Then in your controller, you can use it as:

```
auth()->user()
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.html)

Comment: @iCode, I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030097/how-to-add-some-textfield-in-form-register-laravel-generator-infyom